# Proof of substitution rule for conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $v: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $X, Y$ random variables. It holds
$$
\mathbb{E}[v(X,Y)|Y=y]=\mathbb{E}[v(X,y)|Y=y], \ y\in R(Y).
$$

What would be a way to start the proof?

I know that I should post what I've tried but my attempts have failed miserably, so I would like a hint...

Answer (score 0):

Given $Y(\omega)=y$, the random variables $V(X(\omega),Y(\omega))=V(X(\omega),y)=U(X(\omega))$, 
with probability measure $\mathbb{P}_{\left.  X\,\right\vert
Y=y}(\mathrm{d}\omega)$, thus the substitution rule.