# Concrete substitution for conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let 
$$X(y) = E[f(\xi, \eta)| \eta = y]$$ and $$Y(y, z) = E[f(\xi, z)|\eta=y]$$
Here $\xi, \eta$ are random variables and $f$ is a function of two variables.

I'd like to prove that $$Y(y, y) = X(y)$$ which is very often used without any comments.

If I rewrite the above equality without any renaming it becomes $$E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta = y] = E[f(\xi,y)|\eta=y]$$ which is tempting to consider obvious, but when I formally tried to prove it, it turned out to be quite challenging. Perhaps there is a way to see why this is true without diving into formal definitions?

P.S.
It seems that this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649498/proof-of-substitution-rule-for-conditional-expectation) has been asked before, but it was poorly formulated and the answer is not satisfactory, because it basically says that it is obvious.

Comment: Do you assume that $\mathbf{P}[\eta=y]>0$?

Comment: No, because I'd like to prove this for variables with continuous distribution too (for discrete variables you can write an explicit formula for the conditional expectation, and the proof is kind of trivial).

Answer (score 0):

You already mention that in the discrete case, assuming $P(\eta=y)>0$, we can write a simple formula
$$
E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y] = \frac{E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}]}{P(\eta=y)}, \quad (\ast)
$$
and it is clear that on the event $\{\eta=y\}$, we have $f(\xi,\eta)=f(\xi,y)$, so this is the same as $E[f(\eta,y)|\eta=y]$.

Let's modify this formula slightly. Using $(\ast)$, we can calculate
\begin{align*}
E[E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]1_{\{\eta=y\}}] &= E\left[\frac{E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}]}{P(\eta=y)}1_{\{\eta=y\}}\right] \\
&= \frac{E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}]}{P(\eta=y)} \cdot P(\eta=y) \\
&= E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}].
\end{align*}
In other words, the conditional expectation $E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]$ satisfies
$$
E[E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]1_{\{\eta=y\}}] = E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}]. \quad (\ast\ast)
$$
This expression is simply saying that the average of $E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]$, computed over only the part of the sample space where $\eta=y$, will be the average of $f(\xi,\eta)$ on that part of the sample space. This seems like a natural property, and this is how this conditional expectation is formally defined for a general distribution $\eta$.
In other words, $E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]$ is the quantity that is uniquely determined by the averaging property in $(\ast\ast)$.

With this definition, you can easily compute
$$
E[E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]1_{\{\eta=y\}}] = E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}] = E[f(\xi,y)1_{\{\eta=y\}}] = E[E[f(\xi,y)|\eta=y]1_{\{\eta=y\}}],
$$
and so $E[f(\xi,\eta)|\eta=y]$ and $E[f(\xi,y)|\eta=y]$ are the same conditional expectation.

I don't know if this answer is satisfying, but the above is meant to illustrate that the basic argument for the discrete case in $(\ast)$ works for the general case. You just need to write things a little differently to avoid problems with $P(\eta=y)$ being zero. So if you feel comfortable with $(\ast)$, basically the same applies in the general case with the correct formalism.

Comment: I just noticed a little problem in this argument. If you define the conditional expectation as you did when $\eta$ is really continuous, that is $\forall y$ $P(\eta=y) = 0$, then $E[f(\xi,\eta)1_{\{\eta=y\}}] = 0$, so the conditional expectation can be set to anything. Reasoning exactly as in your answer, I have been able to prove this property, so I will mark the question as answered, but it would be great if you change the incorrect definition to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think you're right and I don't see how to resolve it. Can you unaccept the answer so I can delete it? You can then answer it with your own proof, or delete the question.